# не возможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

хочу проверить отправку сообщений в область уведомлений. и понял что для этого надо создать класс, в котором надо реализовать интерфейсы. но я не понимаю какие нужно реализовать. компилятор пишет только что не возможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса. в android studio на java можно наследуюсь получить сразу все функции, которые нужно переопределить. но здесь я не разбираюсь совсем. я написал класс.

```
#include "notify.h"

void notify::set_info() { SetBalloonInfo(L"test", L"hello", NIF_INFO); }
void notify::show() { Show(NULL, 3000, NULL); }

#if 0
HRESULT notify::OnBalloonUserClick(POINT* pt) { return 0; }

HRESULT notify::OnContextMenu(POINT* pt) { return 0; }

HRESULT notify::OnLeftClick(POINT* pt) { return 0; }
#endif
```

notify.h

```
#pragma once
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
class notify : public IUserNotification2, public IUserNotificationCallback {
 public:
  void set_info();
  void show();

  #if 0
  HRESULT OnBalloonUserClick(POINT *pt);
  HRESULT OnContextMenu(POINT *pt);
  HRESULT OnLeftClick(POINT *pt);
  #endif
};
```

Comment: Грубо говоря - все, которые в предках указаны как абстрактные (написано после них `= 0`).

Comment: @Harry я это знаю. но это надо увидеть в классе. мне что надо искать в заголовочных файлах? Вы знаете как мне решить проблему, чтобы можно было вывести сообщение в области уведомлений?

Comment: @Harry я посмотрел. IUserNotification2 тоже несколько виртуальных функций. но если они виртуальные, то как мне выводить сообщения?

Comment: бред какойто...

Comment: В вашем коде? нет, не знаю. В своей программе я использовал просто Windows API - [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona), без всяких классов... Откуда-то же вы берете эти классы? На них явно должна быть документация...

Comment: @Harry а какая функция отвечает за вывод сообщения Shell_NotifyIcon?

Comment: Щас хотел попробовать функцию ShellMessageBoxW, Но компилятор ругается: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ.

Comment: @Harry а всё разобрался. спасибо что указали что всё таки Shell_NotifyIcon показывает сообщения. наконецто получилось. спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас реализованы не все чистые виртуальные функции; и те что есть, реализованы неправильно (нет virtual) и под блоком `#if 0`, поэтому они вообще не учитываются. Чтобы создать заготовку для всех нужных реализаций, в Visual Studio, например, можно использовать рефакторинг: правой кнопкой по интерфейсу -> *Быстрые действия и рефакторинг* -> *Реализовать чистые виртуальные функции для ...*.

[image: refactoring]

Либо просто скопировать определение интерфейса и заменить все "=0" на реализацию. Вот минимально компилируемая заготовка для вашего класса:

```
class notify : public IUserNotification2, public IUserNotificationCallback {
public: 

    // Унаследовано через IUserNotification2
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetBalloonInfo(LPCWSTR pszTitle, LPCWSTR pszText, DWORD dwInfoFlags) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetBalloonRetry(DWORD dwShowTime, DWORD dwInterval, UINT cRetryCount) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetIconInfo(HICON hIcon, LPCWSTR pszToolTip) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Show(IQueryContinue * pqc, DWORD dwContinuePollInterval, IUserNotificationCallback * pSink) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR pszSoundName)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    // Унаследовано через IUserNotificationCallback
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnBalloonUserClick(POINT * pt) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnLeftClick(POINT * pt) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnContextMenu(POINT * pt) override
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Возможно, вам все это не нужно, [посмотрите более простые примеры для работы с уведомлениями](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area#notifications-and-the-notification-area).

Comment: Не особо занимаюсь Плюсами, поэтому немного нубский, но всё же интересный вопрос: а компилятор разве не выводит отсутствующие чисто виртуальные методы? Он что, просто ругается без пояснений?

Comment: @AivanF. Конкретно Visual C++ 2017 выводит список нереализованных функций, но это сообщение имеет тип "note", а не "error", и не отображается в списке ошибок, который выбран по умолчанию. Чтобы его увидеть, нужно либо переключиться на вкладку "Вывод", либо навести на подчеркнутую строку кода и посмотреть всплывающую подсказку.